# AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

while I am trying to run the `Parking_Slot_mask_rcnn.py` file I got the error as follows in `mrcnn/model.py` file how can I solve

**> 2021-06-17 08:25:18.585897: W

> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll';  dlerror:
> cudart64_110.dll not found 2021-06-17 08:25:18.586852: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart
> dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine. Using
> TensorFlow backend. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "Parking_Slot_mask_rcnn.py", line 20, in 
> import coco   File "C:\Users\nusry\Desktop\parkingslot-master\coco.py", line 56, in
>
> from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils   File "C:\Users\nusry\Desktop\parkingslot-master\mrcnn\model.py", line 268,
> in 
> class ProposalLayer(KE.Layer): AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer**

here all the import in this model file file

```
import os
import random
import datetime
import re
import math
import logging
from collections import OrderedDict
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras.backend as K
import keras.layers as KL
import keras.engine as KE
import keras.models as KM

from mrcnn import utils
```

And this is line No 268 Code:

```
class ProposalLayer(KE.Layer):
```

Installed:

```
  Tensorflow version Version: 2.5.0
    
  Keras  Version Version: 2.2.0
```

Please help me to sort out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are getting this error because of the compatibility issue between `Tensorflow` and `Keras`. You see under the hood `Keras` uses `Tensorflow` for various matrix manipulation.

I will recommend you to upgrade `Keras` and downgrade `Tensorflow`

```
 pip install keras==2.4.3

 pip install tensorflow==2.4.1
```

I have these versions and I was successfully able to run the code.

[image: Keras Engine Layers Screenshot]

Comment: it is ok to use python 3.7

Comment: @Nusry Yes, its fine

Comment: After the installation, I get this error  in Keras initializers ` LOCAL.GENERATED_WITH_V2 = tf.__internal__.tf2.enabled()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.__internal__' has no attribute 'tf2'`

Comment: @Nusry ohh okay, well in that case can you try `!pip install tensorflow==2.1` and let us know did it resolve the issue

Comment: Thanks. I just deleted the Keras file from my virtual environment and tried with your version It works

Answer (score 2):

You should use: keras.layers.Layer instead (KL.Layer)

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, needed to change both instances of `KE.Layer` to `KE.base_layer.Layer` in the `model.py` file.
Works perfectly after.