# I was working on Mask RCNN so while executing demo.ipynb on jupyter notebook i got an error can anyone please help me out

Tags: python-3.x, keras, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision, data-science

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
14 sys.path.append(ROOT_DIR)  # To find local version of the library
15 from mrcnn import utils
---> 16 import mrcnn.model as modellib
17 from mrcnn import visualize
18 # Import COCO config

~\ComputerVisionProject\Mask_RCNN_CustomDataset\Mask_RCNN-master\Mask_RCNN-master\mrcnn\model.py in 
253
254
--> 255 class ProposalLayer(KE.Layer):
256     """Receives anchor scores and selects a subset to pass as proposals
257     to the second stage. Filtering is done based on anchor scores and

AttributeError: **module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'keras.engine' has no attribute 'Layer'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68012351/attributeerror-module-keras-engine-has-no-attribute-layer)
Probably need to install correct package, check the solution mentioned in this issue

Answer (score 0):

!pip install tensorflow==1.15 keras==2.0.8
Install the above version then restart the run time it will work